# What options exist for a "divine bard" in D&D 3.5?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, bard

One character I'm considering playing in a 3.5e D&D game is a dwarvish bard (yes, I know that's a really bad idea from a min-max perspective, and no, I don't care!). The back story for the character would have him growing up in and around a temple and picking up his musical skills there, so I was looking for some options to make the bard "more divine".

Two options I'm aware of are the [Divine Bard](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/variantCharacterClasses.htm) from *Unearthed Arcana* (p. 50) and the *Healing Hymn* and *Hymn of Fortification* options from *Complete Champion* (p. 46-47). Are there any other official options I'm missing, and how balanced are all those options?

Comment: Do you have any preferences beyond 'Divine'?  Do you want to buff the party, be nonviolent, be empowered with the theme of any specific god?

Comment: Apologies for the slow replies here. I forgot completely about this one :-( Mostly thinking as a buffing character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There's a lot of stuff, actually.

**ACFs**

**Inspire Turning -**  Trade Inspire Competence for the ability to empower Turning attempts.  (*Expedition to Castle Ravenloft, p 206*)

**Inspire Awe -** Trade Inspire Courage for Inspire Awe.  (*Dragon Magic, p 13*)

**Repel Domination -** Lose Suggestion. +2 bonus on saves vs mind affecting spells and abilities of the undead, if you succeed in the save they become shaken. (*Expedition to Castle Ravenloft, p 206*)

**Feats**

**Initiate of Milil, From Smite To Song, Devoted Performer** - Takes a paladin, makes it Bardic, Bard and Paladin levels stack for *stuff*.

**Ironskin Chant, Chant of Fortitude, Epic of the Lost King** - Dwarvenly appropriate.

...

Actually i'm going through this and it's all very situational.  Do you want to be the Divine Bard of what, Pelor?  Healing adding feats are a thing, elysian thrushes, whatnot.  Some frost god(dess)?  **Snowflake Wardance, Ice Harmonics**.  Moradin?  **Words of Creation**, why not.

But without any context beyond 'divine', I can't really go anywhere.

I can say that the Bard/Cleric (or Paladin(Wary Swordknight)) of Milil/Spellsinger/Fochluchan Lyrist is a thing of beauty and fun to play.

The Orc (or Dwarf) Battle Drummer is pretty good too.

But yeah, without context I can't really.. suggest anything.

For me, a Dwarvish Bard is a fighting/drinking Bard.  Someone rough and tumble, so something with two razor-sharp axes, a foot-tapping jig, and a snowflake wardance right through the ol' trachea.  Or perhaps someone with a big ol' set of scottish pipes, piping the party into battle and maximizing those inspire courage bonuses.

Healing Bard, Fighting Bard, Buffing Bard, Sneaky Bard, Nasty Bard, Summoner Bard, Bard Admixture, Secret Bard, there's a lot of kinds of Bard, and lot of feats for said bards.  But you really need to know what kind of bard you want to be, first.

Answer (score 2):

From *Races of Stone* you have the Divine Prankster prestige class, which is a combination Bard/Cleric. Somewhat limited in that you have to be a Gnome and follow Garl Glittergold. Also you need ranks in Perform(Comedy), which may or may not suit your personality and roleplaying style.

*Complete Divine* has the Evangelist prestige class, which lets your Bard act as the mouthpiece for a deity. It uses Perform(Oration) to buff allies and cower enemies. Levels in Evangelist also stack with Bard levels for determining strength of bardic music abilities.

I'd recommend reading through all of the options in *Complete Divine*, actually. It has several prestige classes that allow arcane casters to take on a more divine role while still gaining access to increased spells per day. However they will not help the other aspects of your Bard, such as bardic knowledge or songs.

Answer (score 0):

Take Requiem Feat from Libris Mortis Book its one of the best ways for you to affect the undead as for clerical spells and Turning attempts these are my options.

Follow a God or religion it helps a lot, trust me;

First Option: Prestige into Evangelist (Complete Divine book)

Second Option: Multi-Class yourself (Cleric or other divine class)

Third Option: Join the Temple raiders of Olidammara (Song and Silence book)